# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path'

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I have an Angular CLI project which I just upgraded to Angular 6. Now when I try to build my app, I get the following errors:

`ERROR in ./node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/jattardi/code/myproject/node_modules/postcss/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/postcss/lib/map-generator.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/jattardi/code/myproject/node_modules/postcss/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/postcss/lib/previous-map.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/jattardi/code/myproject/node_modules/postcss/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/WritableStream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/jattardi/code/myproject/node_modules/htmlparser2/lib'`

I'm confused. First off, I am not even using `postcss` or `htmlparser2` directly in my project. So they must be dependencies of something else.

But aren't `path` and `stream` built in Node modules? How could it not be able to resolve them?

Comment: Looks like a known [`angular-cli` issue (#10681)](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10681#issuecomment-389153464).

Comment: Also recommended (if you haven't already): https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet? I'm running in the same problem. I fixed the "stream" error using a tsconfig.json path to readable-stream, but can't figure out a solution to the "path" error.

Answer (score 56):

```
npm install path
npm install stream
```

did the trick

Comment: See here for more explanation: https://www.amadousall.com/angular-cli-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve/

I disagree w/ NG team's opinion but this will work I guess

Comment: So randomly, my application started doing this. and this fixed my issue. i reverted my code, and started over and this went away /facepalm

Comment: It worked but now it is asking for a process. Any idea?
`module.exports = {
    commands: [pageCommands],

    elements: require('../lib/util.js').getElements( process,
              require('path').basename(__filename).replace('.js','') )
};`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using webpack5:

1. Install: `yarn add path-browserify or npm install path-browserify`
2. Add this into global webpack settings:

   ```
   resolve: {
        fallback: { 
            path: require.resolve("path-browserify") }
    },
   ```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, VSCode inserted import response from 'express' at the top of my file in angular.

```
    import { response } from 'express';
```

I delete the above import line and then the problem is resolved, all the errors like

- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib'

are gone after the above change.

Comment: I got the same errors from accidentally adding 
`import { Router } from 'express`

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though your source-map-support module needs the path module to proceed and it can't find said module:

Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\project\node_modules\source-map-support'

Perhaps you could try installing this module and see if this resolves your issue:

npm install --save path
Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

in my case tried **npm install path** in terminal and it worked for me !

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as the answer above.